# Unit Testing ServiceLayer with lambda and Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to test a lambda that is used on my repository by my service layer using Moq.

The Service:

```
public class CompanyService : TuneUpLog.ServiceLayer.ICompanyService
{
    private IRepository<Company> _repository;
    private IValidationDictionary _validatonDictionary;
    private Guid _userId;

    public CompanyService(Guid userId,IValidationDictionary validationDictionary, ObjectContext context)
        : this(userId, validationDictionary, new Repository<Company>(context))
    {
    }

    public CompanyService(Guid userId, IValidationDictionary validationDictionary, IRepository<Company> repository)
    {
        _validatonDictionary = validationDictionary;
        _repository = repository;

        if (userId == Guid.Empty)
            throw new SecurityException("UserId is required");
        else
            _userId = userId;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Company> ListCompany()
    {
        return _repository.Find(c => c.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == _userId));
    }
}
```

The Test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void ListCompany_1Valid1Invalid_ReturnsValidCompany()
    {
        Mock<IRepository<Company>> fakeCompanyRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Company>>();

        CompanyService companyService = new CompanyService(USER_ID, new ModelStateWrapper(_modelState), fakeCompanyRepository.Object);

        //1 company for this user and 1 that isn't for this user
        List<Company> companies = new List<Company>()
            {
                new Company() { Id = 1, Name = "Test Company", AccountTypeId = 1, Users = { new User() { UserId = USER_ID } } },
                new Company() { Id = 2, Name = "2nd Test Company", AccountTypeId = 1, Users = { new User() { UserId = Guid.Empty } } }
            };

        fakeCompanyRepository.Setup(c => c.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Company, bool>>>())).Returns(companies.AsQueryable());

        //count should be 1
        Assert.AreEqual(1, companyService.ListCompany().Count());
    }
```

The Repository:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    void Add(T newEntity);
    void Edit(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryable<T> FindAll();
    T FindById(int id);
    void Remove(T entity);
    void Attach(T entity);
}
```

The Test is returning both companies instead of the 1st company that I expect.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does a breakpoint tell you when you put one in the ListCompany() method?

Comment: A breakpoint in the ListCompany method doesn't tell me much since the repository is mocked.  Here is the Mock information on the repository but it doesn't seem like it would be much help:   Behavior Loose Moq.MockBehavior
  CallBase false bool
  DefaultValue Empty Moq.DefaultValue

Comment: Exactly, so if the repository is mocked...it only seems logical to me that the filter on the userid does not get applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use the same technique. You can capture the Expression being passed in when setting up the mock like so

```
fakeCompanyRepository.Setup(
  u => u.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Company, bool>>>()))
  .Returns(
     //Capture the It.IsAny parameter
     (Expression<Func<Company, bool>> expression) => 
     //Apply it to your queryable.
        companies.AsQueryable().Where(expression));
```

This will apply your expression to the companies collection.

Comment: This does work but it feels a bit hacky to me.  Would it be more correct to implement a fake repository that stores a List<T> in memory and use that with the service layer instead?

Comment: You are technically making a fake repository. However if you look at my IRepository/IUnitOfWork combination, I have an InMemoryUnitOfWork that I use for testing. http://azurecoding.net/blogs/brownie/archive/2010/09/22/irepository-lt-t-gt-and-iunitofwork.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your mock repository has been set up to return both the companies, which is why you get them both back.

You should be writing a unit test for the repository to check that the lambdas are executed correctly. In the service layer, the unit test only needs to verify that the repository has been called with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up your mock Find method to return a list of two objects, the userId check inside the lambda supplied is bypassed by this setup